# Unable to push elements to Interface Collection in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, interface

I have two interfaces like below:

```
 export interface ICard
 {
     cardNumber:string;
     cardAddress: string;
     city: string;
 }
 export interface IStudent
 {
     cards: ICard[];
     name:string;
  }
```

In my typescript(.ts) file, i have initialized below in my class

```
   private student: IStudent = <IStudent>{}; // Initializing my interface;
   private cardDetails: ICard[];        // Unable to use the same initialization like above
```

In my function, below i was trying to add multiple cards to my cardDetails and assigning cardDetails to my IStudent interface.

```
    loadStudentCards()
    {
       var card: ICard = <ICard>{}// Initializing here.
        card.cardNumber = "12345";
        card.cardAddress = "Some address";
        card.city = "Seattle";

       this.cardDetails.push(card); //  This is the place i am seeing error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"
         this.student.cards = this.cardDetails;
       }
```

This is the place i am seeing error "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

This might be simple question, but not sure on how to initialize the interface array object here. Can someone throw a hint here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below code which is much readable and best practice as well

```
loadStudentCards()
    {
       let card: ICard = {
               cardNumber : "12345",
               cardAddress : "Some address",
               city : "Seattle"
       }
       this.cardDetails= new Array<ICard>();

       this.cardDetails.push(card); 
       this.student.cards = this.cardDetails;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is considered "best practice" to use `variableName = new Array()` instead of `variableName = []`?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you haven't assigned any value to `cardDetails`.
It should be:

```
var cardDetails: ICard[] = [];
```

Also, you can use the other form of type assertion (casting):

```
var student: IStudent = {} as IStudent;
```

Last thing, you can't use `var` (or `let`/`const`) when defining class members, it should be:

```
class MyClass {
    private cardDetails: ICard[] = []; 
    ...
}
```

Not sure if it's an actual part of your code or you just posted an example.

Comment: Thanks much ! Yeah, i just posted a sample as per my code as my interfaces are different than what i posted. You are right, i had "private" variables in my code, but it was typo when posting my question. Finally, this worked ! :)